# Laravel : 500 Internal Server Error for all routes other than '/'

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

It was little strange but it was happening. I have found solution [here](http://laravel.io/forum/02-20-2014-500-internal-server-error-for-all-routes-other-than?page=1#reply-4017)

Solution was in `.htaccess` file and not in php. It required to change in the .htaccess file for line

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]
```

The same was working fine on one server but not on another.

I want to understand this behavior. Why this was happening?

Comment: If you get a server error then **check your logs**. My guess is the difference between `index.php` and `/index.php`.

Comment: @RajanRawal: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.